# What does "crack down on 100 character titles and stones" mean?

Tags: meaning

I can't correctly understand meaning of this sentence in text below: *"They are also cracking down on the 100 character titles and stones for jewelry sellers."*

I can't understand what they (Amazon as I understand) want to block or stop.

> I've been a pretty big shop on Etsy for a while, but Amazon has been catching up fast.  I have over 1800 items on my main Etsy shop and only 209 listed on H@A.  October they were tied.  I sent in only one item for FBA and my sales soared!  I highly recommend listing as much as you can on H@A and being very diligent about the H@A seo - not duplicating keywords or tags - using words only once in the title / description, etc.  They are also cracking down on the 100 character titles and stones for jewelry sellers.
>
> A few other top sellers have told me that Amazon now outsells their Etsy shops 4 to 1.  I can't wait to see what Christmas brings!"
>
> — [NovaWildstar on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/handmadeamazon/comments/4m43zj/your_sales_on_etsy_vs_handmade_at_amazon/)

Comment: A 100 character title is a title containg 100 letters, numbers, punctuation marks, etc. Maybe Amazon considers these too long.

Comment: A jewellery seller sells "stones", i.e. gemstones. It's impossible to know exactly what is going on from the excerpt, but maybe they're taking action against fake or misdescribed gemstones. I can't see any other meaning, though.

Comment: From [Amazon Jewelry Support](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/yay-amazon-is-cracking-down-on-fake-jade/4710) 2014 - *All sellers using the word “jade” incorrectly in their listings will be subject to negative actions on their account, including and up to permanent removal of their jewelry selling privileges.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'crack down on' something is an English idiomatic expression, probably connected the horsewhip or something like that.  The Cambridge English Dictionary gives the definition

> Start dealing with bad or illegal behaviour in a more severe way.

That graphic idea of a crack of the whip then spreads to the idea of forbidding or forcefully dealing with prohibited actions (here exceeding some permitted limit to the number of characters to be used or the use of hackneyed and overblown similes to precious stones.